# Reverse tracking a XMLNode from a Treeview Nod

Tags: .net, xml

I have assigned a XMLNodeList and its child nodes collection to a Treeview..
I get to see all the data on the treeview..

Now i select a treeview node item. I now want to get the XMLNode associated with it.
Basically i want the conversion from a **TreeNode ---> XMLNode**
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlIntrospection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class XmlNodeTree : TreeNode
        {
            private XmlNode mNode;
            public XmlNode Node
            {
                get { return mNode; }
            }

            public XmlNodeTree(XmlNode node)
            {
                mNode = node;
                if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    Text = node.InnerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    Text = node.Name;
                }

                if (node.Attributes != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlAttribute a in node.Attributes)
                    {
                        Text += " " + a.OuterXml;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private XmlDocument doc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            doc = new XmlDocument();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fill the tree View with xml Node recurcively
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"> current Tree node </param>
        /// <param name="l"> current xml node </param>
                private void FillTreeView(TreeNodeCollection c,XmlNodeList l)
                {
                    if (l == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    foreach (XmlNode e in l)
                    {
                        XmlNodeTree n = new XmlNodeTree(e);
                        c.Add(n);
                        FillTreeView(n.Nodes, e.ChildNodes);
                    }
                }

        private void Init()
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }


        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    Init();
                    doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    XmlNodeTree root = new XmlNodeTree(doc.LastChild);
                    textBox1.Text = doc.InnerXml;
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
                    FillTreeView(root.Nodes,doc.LastChild.ChildNodes);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File " + openFileDialog1.FileName + " no valid xml file");
                }
            }
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
           XmlNodeTree currentNode = (XmlNodeTree) e.Node;
           propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = currentNode.Node;
        }       
    }
}
```